# Bootstrap noConlict usage

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm learning Bootstrap's javascript code, here is an example, I wonder the way they are using noConflict, here is a piece of code:

```
var old = $.fn.tab;

$.fn.tab = function () {
  // do something
}

$.fn.tab.noConflict = function () {
  $.fn.tab = old // set $.fn.tab to undefined
  return this
}


var s = $.fn.tab.noConflict();
console.log(s, $.fn.tab) // do something
                         // undefined
```

I wonder why `return this` could still get function's value while it's set to `undefined`, is it a problem of reference/value?

tks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$.fn.tab` is not yet defined(if not exists) when we set variable `old` to `$.fn.tab`

As soon as we call method `noConflict`, `$.fn.tab` will be set to `$.fn.tab` predefined(or undefined), and `$.fn.tab` we defined will be returned to variable we defined(here is `s`)